# google oauth access token 411 response

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-api, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm working with google's OAuth api for web server applications, specifically asp.net mvc, and i'm able to get to the point where google returns an authorization code for a certain oauth request. At that point, I'm trying to obtain the access token using the following code:

```
public ActionResult GetOAuthToken()
{
     HttpWebRequest myReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(OAuthConfig.getTokenUrl(Request.QueryString["code"].ToString()));
     myReq.Method = "POST";
     myReq.Host = "accounts.google.com";
     myReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
     WebResponse resp = myReq.GetResponse();
     return View();
 }
```

The OAuthConfig is just a class I wrote that contains a method getTokenUrl(), which returns a url with parameters such as code, client_secret, client_id etc. for the url: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token. I've debugged and checked that there's nothing wrong with this url.

I keep getting the following error: The remote server returned an error: (411) Length Required.

I don't know what to specify for the content length, or if there's something else that i need to include to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to have a look at [Google-API .NET Client](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/OAuth2)?

If you debug you will see Google uses "length" as an internal property when sending access-token request. you can try to fix it on your own, but you can use THEIR class in order to send the token request; If you use their class you do not have to worry about internal such as length...

Comment: I have downloaded that library multiple times, but for reason when I extract the zip file, it just says 'Can't open the file google-api-dot-net-client.zip', so I'm unable to use google's client library.

Comment: if you find it hard to open the zip file (might be corrupted, etc) - try to solve this issue and proceed; I do not think it is a good reason for implementing stuff by your own when you have it implemented by Google... Try to understand why it cannot be opened in your env.